# Pure Data on Raspberry Pi with USB Controller not working

Tags: usb

I have a [Pure Data](https://puredata.info/) patch that run before booting in the `rc.local` directory. The patch is starting nicely but my raspberry doesn't recognize my [korg nanokontrol2](http://www.korg.com/us/products/computergear/nanokontrol2/).

But, when I start the script manually, which looks like this:

```
sleep 20;
pd-extended -nogui /home/pi/mypatch.pd &
```

It works perfectly.

As you see I already tried to let my raspi sleep before starting.

Any ideas?

Comment: `rc.local` **DOES NOT** "run before booting" but "at the end of each multiuser runlevel" i.e. effectively the last step before logging in - so you need to specify **full paths** for all files.

Comment: Welcome - This is a Q&A site. The point is to ask a specific question so that other users can give you concise answers. Your question is pretty good and to the point allowing for good quality answers. Be kind and up vote people that take time to answer and look like good suggestions. Please read the FAQ too and hope to see you around. Have Fun

Answer (score 2):

Put the full path to `pd-extended` in the command and use `nohup` to make it immune to hangups:

```bsh
nohup /usr/local/bin/pd-extended -nogui /home/pi/mypatch.pd >> /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

You can also log all output to a file:

```bsh
LOG_FILE="/home/pi/mypatch.log"
nohup /usr/local/bin/pd-extended -nogui /home/pi/mypatch.pd >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the Korg show up in the output of `lsusb`? USB midi has been working fairly well on the Raspberry Pi for a few years now.